# Simple Exponential Smoothing Forecasts are not Plotting on Top of Actual Data in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, statsmodels

I am using the SimpleExpSmoothing from the statsmodels package.  I created a time-series dataframe. I am able to create the plots for the forecast and the actual data.  But when I try to plot them together they display as separate plots.  I would like to plot the forecast plots on top of the actual data.

I am using statsmodels 0.9.0, python 3.6.8 and matplotlib 3.0.2

```
# Simple Exponential Smoothing
fit1 = SimpleExpSmoothing(df1).fit(smoothing_level=0.2,optimized=False)
fcast1 = fit1.forecast(12).rename(r'$\alpha=0.2$')
# plot
fcast1.plot(marker='o', color='blue', legend=True)
fit1.fittedvalues.plot(marker='o',  color='blue')



fit2 = SimpleExpSmoothing(df1).fit(smoothing_level=0.6,optimized=False)
fcast2 = fit2.forecast(12).rename(r'$\alpha=0.6$')
# plot
fcast2.plot(marker='o', color='red', legend=True)
fit2.fittedvalues.plot(marker='o', color='red')


fit3 = SimpleExpSmoothing(df1).fit()
fcast3 = fit3.forecast(12).rename(r'$\alpha=%s$'%fit3.model.params['smoothing_level'])
# plot
fcast3.plot(marker='o', color='green', legend=True)
fit3.fittedvalues.plot(marker='o', color='green')

df1.plot()

plt.show()
```

I have two plots, one with all the forecast plots and  one plot with the actual data.  I would like one plot with the forecast on top of actual.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have to do with Statsmodels, it's just how Pandas plotting works. One way to make sure they all plot in the same figure is to construct the figure yourself and then pass the axis explicitly:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# ...

fcast1.plot(ax=ax, marker='o', color='blue', legend=True)
fit1.fittedvalues.plot(ax=ax, marker='o',  color='blue')

# etc.

df1.plot(ax=ax)
```